# How to get correct indentation for function with no return type in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am using C++ mode to write some code.
I found that for some function without a return type, the indentation is wrongly done (indented to start of line). One frequent case is the constructor for class type, e.g.

```
 class Person {
 public:
 Person(const std::string &s): name(s) { }
 Person(const std::string &s0, const std::string &s1): name(s0), address(s1) { }

 private:
   std::string name = "Default_Name";
   std::string address = "Default_Addr";
 }
```

The colon before initializer list may also be a cause.

Question:
Is there away to fix this?

Comment: Try Ctrl-C Ctrl-S on the line to see how it's being indented.  Your current indentation looks suspiciously like it's being treated as C code, though, and not C++ code.

Comment: @neal Brilliant! I just found out I am indeed in C mode. I has been writing C++ programs. The source files are OK because they end with .cpp. But when I come to write headers, the .h file ext name lead emacs to think it is C file. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, I've been bitten by that before, too.  Best solution depends on whether you think you will be writing a lot of C code,too.  If you will be, then you can name your C++ headers with ".hh" at the end, so Emacs knows.  

<p>

Or, you can set a file local variable that sets the mode: [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html)

Or you can modify auto-mode-alist in your .emacs:

    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formatting for comments is not very good so I'm answering here:

Yeah, I've been bitten by that before, too.  Best solution depends on whether you think you will be writing a lot of C code,too.  If you will be, then you can name your C++ headers with ".hh" at the end, so Emacs knows.

Or, you can set a file local variable that sets the mode: [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html)

Or, if you will not be writing a lot of C code,  you can modify auto-mode-alist in your .emacs so that .h defaults to c++ mode:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode))
```